# A logic riddle from "The Lady or the Tiger?" by Raymond Smullyan

Tags: logic, puzzle

**Just to clarify, Case 3 and Case 4 must have flawed reasoning in order to reconcile my proof with the author's.**

I have been having a problem with a particular riddle from Raymond Smullyan and I can't seem to reconcile my proof with his solution. I am more inclined to think I am wrong, but to myself my proof looks quite convincing. Maybe you'll be able to point out the flaw in my logic.

Background: There are natives on the Isle of Questioners that are either of Type A or Type B. People of Type A may only ask questions to which the correct answer is "Yes" such as "Does 2 + 2 = 4?". People of Type B may only ask questions to which the correct answer is "No" such as "Does 2 + 2 = 5?". Furthermore there are people who have wandered onto the island who are either sane or insane. People who are sane are completely sane and believe all true things, they will always answer honestly and accurately. People who are insane are completely insane and believe all untrue things, they will always answer honestly and inaccurately. And all parties involved have perfect knowledge of the universe, but whether they are correct or incorrect about it depends on their sanity.

Problem: You meet a native and a sane or insane person named Thomas. The native asks Thomas, "Do you believe I am the type who could ask you whether you are insane?" What can be deduced about the native, and what can be deduced about Thomas?

My (failed?) attempt at a solution: There are four cases: the native is Type A and Thomas is sane, the native is Type A and Thomas is insane, the native is Type B and Thomas is sane, and the native is Type B and Thomas is sane. (In Case 1 and 2 my proof follows the author's almost exactly. Smullyan simply says of Case 3 and 4, "The only way out of the contradiction is that the native must be of Type B rather than Type A" but I still reach a contradiction.)

Case 1: Suppose that the native is Type A. Then the answer to the question is "Yes" and Thomas must believe that the native can ask whether he is insane. Now suppose that Thomas is sane, which means that Thomas must be correct in his belief. So the correct answer to the question "Are you insane?" when posed to Thomas must be "Yes" since the native could ask the question. Thus Thomas is insane as well as sane and this is a contradiction. The first case is impossible.

Case 2: Suppose that the native is Type A. Then the answer to the question is "Yes" and Thomas must believe that the native can ask whether he is insane. Now suppose Thomas is insane, which means that Thomas must be incorrect in his belief. So the correct answer to the question "Are you insane?" when posed to Thomas must be "No" since the native could not ask the question. (Thomas would indeed say "No" but be incorrect because he is insane and believes he is sane.) Thus Thomas is sane as well as insane and this is a contradiction. The second case is impossible.

Case 3: Suppose that the native is Type B. Then the answer to the question is "No" and Thomas must believe that the native can not ask whether he is insane. Now suppose Thomas is sane, which means that Thomas must be correct in his belief. So the correct answer to the question "Are you insane?" when posed to Thomas must be "Yes" since the native could not ask the question. Thus Thomas is insane as well as sane and this is a contradiction. The third case is impossible.

Case 4: Suppose that the native is Type B. Then then answer to the question is "No" and Thomas must believe that the native can not ask whether he is insane. Now suppose Thomas is insane, which means that Thomas must be incorrect in his belief. So the correct answer to the question "Are you insane?" when posed to Thomas must be "No" since the native could ask the question. Thus Thomas is sane as well as insane and this is a contradiction. The fourth case is impossible.

Can you see a flaw in my logic? I've tried to re-approach this problem and poke holes in my own proof, but I can't reach any other conclusion other than this encounter between the native and Thomas must have been impossible.

Comment: An insane person answers a question incorrectly, but does he/she **believe** that incorrect answer?

Comment: As the author says, insane people are completely insane and earnestly believe all incorrect things and disbelieve all correct things. They do not do so out of malice but merely pure insanity.

Comment: You should correct that in the question. Currently the question says "People who are sane insane are completely insane and will always answer questions incorrectly." and doesn't mention their beliefs.

Comment: Also there seems to be an implicit assumption that Thomas and the native know each other's types; it would be helpful to make that explicit.

Comment: @joriki Thank you. I've incorporated both of your suggestions. I think the riddle is more explicit now.

Comment: "Whether you are insane" is slightly ambiguous: we need to know the precise wording of the question to see if the appropriate answer is "Yes" or "No".  Perhaps change this to "are you insane"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can analyze this question using boolean algebra. Let $p$ represent whether the native is type A (true) or type B (false), and let $q$ represent whether Thomas is sane (true) or insane (false).

The statement "Can the native ask the question 'Is Thomas insane?'" is logically equivalent to $p\oplus q$, where $\oplus$ is XOR or exclusive or.

The statement "Does Thomas believe that the native can ask the question 'Is Thomas insane?'" is logically equivalent to $(p\oplus q)\Leftrightarrow q$, which is equivalent to $\neg p$. Here, $\Leftrightarrow$ represents "if and only if".

The statement "Can the native ask 'Do you believe I am the type who could ask you whether you are insane?'" is logically equivalent to $\neg p\Leftrightarrow p$, which is always **false**.

Comment: I just want to say that this breakdown is beautiful. Thank you for typing this out for me. This is a very different proof than my own that is really iron clad. I may have to see now if I can convert some other puzzles in the book into boolean algebra.

Answer (score 3):

Oops: my previous analysis was wrong.  A type A native asks a question for which the **correct** answer, not necessarily the answer that will be returned, is Yes.

If  a proposition $Q$ is true, a sane Thomas believes it, and an insane Thomas does not.   If $Q$ is false, a sane Thomas does not believe it, and
an insane Thomas does.

So: a type A native can ask Thomas "do you believe $Q$?" if and only 
Thomas believes $Q$, i.e. either $Q$ is true and Thomas is sane or $Q$ is false and Thomas is insane.  A type B native can ask "do you believe $Q$?" if
$Q$ is true and Thomas is insane or $Q$ is false and Thomas is sane.
There are four possibilities, which I'll denote $(A,Q,S)$, $(A,\neg {Q},\neg{S})$, $(\neg A,  Q, \neg S)$, $(\neg A, \neg Q, S)$.

In this case $Q$ is "I am the type who could ask you "are you insane".
$Q$ is true iff the native is type A and Thomas is insane or the native is type B and Thomas is sane.   In the same notation as above, the possibilities are $(A, Q, \neg S)$, $(\neg A, Q, S)$, $(A, \neg Q, S)$, $(\neg A, \neg Q, \neg S)$.

The intersection of these two sets is empty.
Thus there is no case where the native could ask "Do you believe I am the type who could ask you "are you insane?"?".

Comment: I think your proof is thorough and correct. However be careful of confusing Q with "Do you believe Q?".  I think I'm convinced now that there is an error in the book.

Comment: I believe I was careful.  However, I might be insane...

Comment: But they're not asking if they can "are you sane?". They are asking if they can ask a question /regarding/ sanity.

Comment: @RobertIsrael It would seem we are all insane for working on this problem for this long.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning for Case 4 might be flawed: If Thomas is insane, then his answer to the question "Are you insane" must be "No". For this reason you could consider this the correct answer to the question, in which case there is no contradiction.

Comment: As the author points out "Are you insane?" and "Do you believe you are insane?" are two entirely different questions. The insane person may say "No" to the former question and "No" to "Does 2 + 2 = 4?" but that does not prevent a Type A person from asking them because the correct answer in both cases actually is "Yes". However a Type A person could not ask an insane person "Do you believe you are insane?" because they would say "No" being wrong in their belief but correct in their answer. Also the author says that no contradiction arises from Case 3 or Case 4.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to *"Are you insane?"* will be *"No"* from anybody who is sane or insane

The type who asks questions with the answer *"No"* is type B, so the original question is equivalent to *"Do you believe I am type B?"*

This can be asked by a Type B native to an insane person, who will give the answer *"No"*, and a Type B person can also ask *"Are you insane?"*

Comment: I agree with the first sentence. But as to the second, that's the question. The question would be changed to _"Do you believe I am the type would ask if I am type B?"_ No one can ask if they are type B. So in order for an insane person to answer _"No"_ they must be correct in their belief thus making them sane. _"Am I the type who can ask whether you are insane?"_ is not the same question as _"Are you insane?"_

Comment: The answer _given_ to the question "Are you insane?" will always be "No," regardless of who is asked but type B's (and type A's) are restricted by the _correct_ answer, so they could only ask a sane person that question, and a type A person could ask it of an insane person, even though the answer they would receive would be "No" (because that answer would be incorrect)

Comment: Gabriel.  But "do you believe you are insane" will be answered yes by an insane person.  An insane person does not believe he is insane, therefore an insane person believes he believes he is insane.

Comment: A type A can ask an insane person are you insane.  The insane person will answer no but the correct answer is yes.  The correct answer is all that matters to type A. Likewise type b.  In fact we can conclude no matter what is asked insane people will answer yes to type B and no to type A.

Comment: Further more.  Both a sane person and an insane person will believe they believe correct things.  The sane person will be correct that he believes correct things.  And the insame person will be incorrect that he believes correct things.  "Do you believe 2 + 2 is 4"  Insane person: "Yes" Because 2+2 = 4 so the insane person doesn't believe it.  So the insane person believes he believes it.  So "Do you believe I am type B" is yes if he is type b and no if he isn't.  So impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow your argument for case 3. The question as posed must be answered "No" if the native is type B; and if Thomas is sane, he will answer "No" truthfully. For if the native asks a sane Thomas, "Are you insane?", then he will answer "No." This will only work if the native is Type B.

Comment: Native is Type B and Thomas is sane ⇒ The answer to the first question is "No" and that is correct, the native could not ask the question. ⇒ The only way a native of Type B could not ask a question is if the correct answer is "Yes" ⇒ So the correct answer when asking Thomas "Are you insane?" is "Yes" ⇒ Thomas must be insane. ⇒ We have a contradiction. Did that make the argument any clearer?

Comment: That helps a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

New answer.  I think Smullyan is wrong.  If the types can ask based on the *correct* answer and not and the responder answer than:

Type A => Thomas believes.

Thomas sane => native is type.  => type a => Thomas insane.  Contradiction.

Thomas insane=> native not type.  Native A => Thomas not insane. Contradiction.

So native type B.

So Thomas Does not believe.

Thomas sane=> Thomas correct and native not type.  Type B => Thomas *is* insane.  Contradiction.

Thomas insane=> Thomas is wrong =I native is type=> Thomas not sane.  Incorrect.

===

Other option.  Type A can ask if answer is answered yes/no whether or not it is actually correct.

Case 1.  Type A.  Sane.

Then answer is yes=>Thomas believes he believes =>Thomas believes => native is type=>Thomas believes he is insane=>Thomas is insane. Contradiction.

Case 2 type A. Insane.

Answer yes => Thomas believes he believes => Thomas doesn't believe native is type=> native is  type=>answer "are you insane" is yes=> Thomas believes he is insane=> Thomas is sane.

contradiction

Case 3 Type B. Sane

Answer is no=>Thomas believes he does not believes native is type=>Thomas does not believe native is type=>native is not type=>answer to are you insane is yes=> Thomas believes he is insane=> Thomas is insane. Contradiction.

Case 4. B. Insane

Answer no=>Thomas believes Thomas does not believe native is type=>Thomas does believe native is type=>native is not type=>answers were to are you insane is yes=>Thomas believes he is insane=> Thomas is sane.  Contradiction.

Impossible

Either way Smullyan is wrong.case is never possible.

==e=e

Ignore rest.  It is wrong.

1, type A.  Thomas is sane.

Are you insane? No.  Thomas answer no

Can I ask you if are insane? No. Thomas answer no.

I'm I the type who can ask? No.  Thomas answer no.

Do you think I am the type? No.  Thomas answer. No.

Can it be asked. No.

2) native type B.  Thomas sane.

Are you insane.  Answer no.

Am I the type who can ask? Yes.

Do you believe I am the type? Yes.

Can the native ask? No.

3) Native type A. Thomas insane.

Are you insane? Answer yes.  Thomas answers No.

Am I the type who can ask? Answer no.  Thomas answer yes.

Do you believe I am the type? Answer yes.  Thomas answer no.

Can native ask? No.

4)type b. Thomas insane.

Are you insane? A: yes. T: no

Am I the type? A yes.  T no.

Do you believe I am the type? A no. A yes.

Can native ask? No.

This situation can not

Comment: Oops the types are if the correct answer is yes no.  Not if the person will answer yes no.